# How to judge a good journal for glaciology?

Tags: glaciology, glaciation

I am trying to find articles/papers related to glacier fluctuations since LIA, how do i quickly analyze if the journal is good? Is impact factor sufficient to judge the journal quickly, if so, what should be the cut off?
Thank you.

Comment: Usually the way to go is to figure out which journal most of the good papers you're citing are published in, and then go for that one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A first approach would be to look at the reference lists of some good articles on glaciology. The reference list should contain several articles from journals that would be of relevance. As a glaciologist I would explicitly mention the following:

- Journal of Glaciology
- Annals of Glaciology
- Journal of Geophysical Research
- The Cryosphere
- Geophysical Research Letters
- Frontiers in Earth Science
- Nature Geoscience

then there will be high profile papers in

- Nature
- Science
- Nature Communications

and a series of other journals such as:

- Arctic, Antarctic and Alpine Research
- Geografiska Annaler Series A: Physical Geography
- Polar Research

Then, because of the cross-disciplinary nature of glaciology, papers will appear in journals with e.g. atmospheric, biological, chemistry, engineering, physics themes.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Can I rely on  "catena" and " water" (water is from mdpi).

Comment: Catena is a soils journal and Water hydrology so not glaciology and usually do not carry much glaciology related. There may be other reasons to avoid Water (mdpi). Again, check what journals commonly appear in the ref-list of a glaciological paper and you get a good view.

Comment: Thank you so much.